# How can I mock rest client from external library in spring boot tests?

Tags: mockito, spring-boot-test, wiremock, mockrestserviceserver

I tried to use MockRestServiceServer to mock rest client from external library but it doesn't work because tested code instantiate its own RestTemplate internally and I don't have access to it.

It seems like MockRestServiceServer only work if the tested client use the same instance of RestTemplate. In my case it is different.

What solution I can use it this case? Can I use wireMock?